# hystrix metrics stream: The 'delay' parameter doesn't work

Tags: hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

My application integrates Hystrix as circuit breaker, and the stream endpoint is exposed at `/hystrix.stream`. Now I want to control the streaming frequency by 'delay' parameter:

```
curl "http://localhost:9000/hystrix.stream?delay=1000"
```

Unfortunately 'delay' doesn't work. I still receive the hystrix metrics data twice per second.

Help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking up to the source code, I found that there's no way to change delay dynamically at all! Hystrix sets this parameter at the app's starting phrase.The only way to change this delay is creating a config file named `config.properties` in classpath, then add the following property:

```
hystrix.stream.dashboard.intervalInMilliseconds=2000
```